# Delete Function from List

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble implementing the delete function, any help would be appreciated. I have a list called memberlist that stores the persons name and number. I have everything working except the delete function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Person
{
    private string name;
    private string phoneNumber;

    public string Name
    {
        set { name = value; }
        get { return name; }
    }
    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        set { phoneNumber = value; }
        get { return phoneNumber; }
    }
    public void PrintInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(" Name: {0}", name);
        Console.WriteLine(" Phone Number: {0}", phoneNumber);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    public void SaveASCII(ref StreamWriter output)
    {

        output.WriteLine(name);
        output.WriteLine(phoneNumber);

    }
    public void LoadASCII(ref StreamReader input)
    {

        name = input.ReadLine();
        phoneNumber = input.ReadLine();

    }

}


public class membershipList
{

    public Person[] ML = null;

    public void AddMember(Person p)
    {
        if (ML == null)
        {
            ML = new Person[1];
            ML[0] = p;
        }
        else
        {
            Person[] temp = ML;
            ML = new Person[temp.Length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; ++i)
            {
                ML[i] = new Person();
                ML[i] = temp[i];
            }
            ML[temp.Length] = new Person();
            ML[temp.Length] = p;
            temp = null;

        }
    }

    public void DeleteMember(string name)
    {

        if (ML == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name + " had not been added before.");
        }
        else
        {
            int memberIndex = ML.MembershipList().FindIndex(p => p.Name == name);
            if (memberIndex = -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name + " had not been added before.");
                return;
            }
            List<Person> tmp = new List<Person>(ML);
            tmp.RemoveAt(memberIndex);
            ML = tmp.ToArray();
        }
    }



    public void PrintAll()
    {
        if (ML != null)
            foreach (Person pers in ML)
                pers.PrintInfo();
        else Console.WriteLine("Then list is empty");
    }
    public void Search(string p)
    {
        if (ML != null)
        {
            foreach (Person pers in ML)
            {
                if (pers.Name.ToLower().CompareTo(p.ToLower()) == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("1 Record Found:");
                    pers.PrintInfo();
                    break;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Record not found.");
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("Then list is empty.");
    }

    public void ReadASCIIFile()
    {
        StreamReader input = new StreamReader("memberlist.dat"); ;

        try
        {

            int num = Convert.ToInt32(input.ReadLine());
            ML = new Person[num];

            for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
            {
                ML[i] = new Person();
                ML[i].LoadASCII(ref input);

            }
            input.Close();
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            input.Close();
        }


    }

    public void SaveASCIIFile()
    {

        StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter("memberlist.dat");

        output.WriteLine(ML.Length);
        foreach (Person pers in ML)
        {
            pers.SaveASCII(ref output);

        }
        output.Close();


    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        membershipList ML = new membershipList();
        ML.ReadASCIIFile();

        string option;
        do
        {

            // Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("MemberShip List MENU");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("     a. Add");
            Console.WriteLine("     b. Seach");
            Console.WriteLine("     c. Delete");
            Console.WriteLine("     d. Print All");
            Console.WriteLine("     e. Exit");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("option: ");
            option = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            switch (option)
            {
                case "a":
                    Person np = new Person();
                    Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
                    np.Name = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Enter PhoneNumber: ");
                    np.PhoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
                    ML.AddMember(np);
                    break;
                case "b":
                    Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
                    string name = Console.ReadLine();
                    ML.Search(name);
                    break;
                case "c":
                    Console.Write("Enter Name to be Deleted:");
                    ML.DeleteMember(name);
                    break;
                case "d":
                    ML.PrintAll();

                    break;
                case "e":
                    ML.SaveASCIIFile();
                    Console.WriteLine("BYE...... ");
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option");
                    break;
            }


        } while (option.ToLower() != "d");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working is very non-descriptive.  What happens when the delete method runs?  An error?  It doesn't delete?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see what's happening?

Comment: Getting this error 1>C:\Users\Zekk Ragnos\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MemberShip\MemberShip\Program.cs(86,38,86,52): error CS1061: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'MembershipList' and no extension method 'MembershipList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem statement is:

```
int memberIndex = ML.MembershipList().FindIndex(p => p.Name == name);
```

`ML` is an array which doesn't contain a member called `MembershipList`.

Maybe this would work better?

```
int memberIndex = Array.FindIndex(ML, p => p.Name == name);
```

Comment: tried this but I still get error  No overload for method 'FindIndex' takes 1 arguments

Comment: `FindIndex` is not an extension method, try `Array.FindIndex(ML, p => p.Name == name)`

Comment: now I get this last error  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Comment: I'm not going to continue to debug your code for you. Walk through the code, figure out where the exception happens and RTFM.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously you need to specify deleted name first in order to delete it, becouse for now you don't read it:

```
case "c":
   Console.Write("Enter Name to be Deleted:");
   ML.DeleteMember(name);
break;
```

Should be:

```
case "c":
   Console.Write("Enter Name to be Deleted:");
   string name = Console.ReadLine();
   ML.DeleteMember(name);
break;
```